# Get the maximum file size that will open under x seconds in every platform

Tags: c#, file, testing

My application will be deployed on different platforms with different hardware. I want to find the maximum file size that will open under x seconds in a user platform, in which I install my application. Is there a way to write a c# script type application or even a  python that will produce a similar behavior to the time the user will spend opening a file?

I thought about creating a file and in a linear way increase it until it takes around x seconds to open, something like:

```
int currentFileSize = 10* (int)Math.pow(2,20) // 20MB;
CreateFile(currentFileSize);

var secondsTook = Testopen performance(currentFileSize); // Measure open time with stopwatch
While (Math.Abs(DesiredTimeInSeconds-SecondsTook)>DesiredTimeInSeconds / 1000) 
{
   // Increase file size somehow.
   // Repeat
}

return currentFileSize;
```

In case I create a completely new file each round, does `File.Open()` take the exact amount of time it takes for a user to open a file through the explorer? And how would you suggest me to do such a test?

Edit:

The idea is that this test will run on each endpoint. According to that test I will set the maximum file length differently in each platform. 
Moreover, In this test my intention is to create a new file each time, and therefore I was hoping to disable anything related to caching of the particular file. Meaning: create file1. Proceed = deleting file1, creating completely new file2. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: The problem with any repeated test is your results will get skewed because of caching

Comment: That test is supposed to run on each deployed platform, and inside that test create a whole new different file each time. Where would caching be involved in this scenario?

Comment: if you use the win apis you can send in FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING to the create file function

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MichaelRandall thats a nice one +1 - by using FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING you are only able to get the "worst" performance for that system - and some flags might be ignored: one of my dearest blogs: [the old new thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140306-00/?p=1583)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not. Your request is IO-Bound which behaves very differently depending on the hardware installed. SSDs are much faster then HDDs, there are hybrid ones etc. You can not get a "number" that works for any system, because it very much depends on the system it is running on.

You also can not do this on each system as "test" because of caching mechanics involved when accessing data from harddrives: if you access a file and access it again it might be taken from the cached data of the harddrive, the second time loading much faster.

To get to reliable data, you would have to somehow circumvent the caching mechanics of the operating system and the hardddrive itself which even if using the correct flags and low-level calls might be ignored by the harddrive: [FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING & FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH -
 The old new thing blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140306-00/?p=1583)

Comment: Please see my updated which explains more of my point of view. The point is to have different results on each different hardware and according to that set the file using this test. Would it still be problematic?

Comment: @S.Peter  The system would still cache data (when reading from the HD the HD has a cache itself, the system might cache as well) - so yes: you can not be sure your "12MB file" is read in 1s because of whatever or because it was (partly) cached already from earlier reads of your test method. : https://www.pcmech.com/article/what-is-hard-drive-cache-and-what-does-it-do/  If a system got a SSD and a HDD (like mine) it also depends which one is used - the SSD is _much_ faster.

Comment: @S.Peter  You write a new file. That one goes through the cache - maybe. How do you guarantee that your following read does aktually read from the disk and not out of the cache...

Comment: But the same applies to the user doesn't it? If the user has read files in the same directory already, that possibly it'll take him less time to open a file in the same directory? It can never be precise this way or another, I'm looking for something "close enough"

Comment: @S.Peter If you want a _ballpark_ - go for it. It won't be exact and you might still need more then `x` seconds to write `y` Mb of file afterwards due to effects out fo your control when performing your tests.